# Ler inputs radio e text do mesmo form

Tags: jquery

preciso de uma luz para algo que estou fazendo.
dentro de um `form` há vários `radios` e alguns `text box`.
Preciso pegar os dados de todos dentro de um `objeto jQuery`.

abaixo um exemplo de como faço contendo somente `inputs` com `checked`.

```
var dados = {"result":[]};
        var objRadio = $('input:checked').each(function(){
            dados.result.push({
                            "id_user"     : idUser,
                            "id_varejo"   : idvarejo,
                            "id_pesquisa" : idPesquisa,
                            "id_pergunta" : $(this).attr('name'),
                            "id_resposta" : $(this).val(),
                            "nome"        : nome,
                            "id_status"   : 7
            }); 
        });
```

e o retorno seria este :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

preciso que nos checks retorne o value dele e nos text box retorne o texto

agradeço se alguem conseguir me dar uma luz

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e colocar o retorno do `json`?

Comment: Oi Rafael, o retorno seria isso mesmo um objeto jquery.

Comment: Isso eu entendi, só gostaria que você pegasse o retorno e posta-se aqui (sem ser imagem), para podermos fazer os testes baseado no retorno que voce já tem.

Comment: Oi Rafael, segue um exemplo do retorno.{"result":[{"id_user":"1","id_varejo":"2768","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"7","id_resposta":"31","nome":"","id_status":7},{"id_user":"1","id_varejo":"2768","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"9","id_resposta":"35","nome":"","id_status":7},{"id_user":"1","id_varejo":"2768","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"11","id_resposta":"37","nome":"","id_status":7}]}

Comment: Voce pode postar seu codigo funcional? no `JSFiddle` ou aqui mesmo? incluindo `HTML` e `JS`

Comment: Seria impossivel pq o projeto é gigante :(

Comment: Mas nao da para postar só essa parte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode compor o valor JQuery selector `$('input:checked, input[type=text]')`. Que no caso que você especificou funciona, já que ambos o inputs respondem seus valores para `.val()`. No caso, um `textarea` responderia para `.text()`.

```js
$('input:checked, input[type=text]').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("type"));
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="37"/>
<input type="text" value="texto no text"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```